# Ladder and friction (wall and floor)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, statics

[Here](http://physicstasks.eu/654/a-leaning-ladder) there is a problem and the proposed solution:
[image: Question]

UPDATE: I can't understand why getting the maximum friction to solve this kind of problem when it is known that static friction, depending on other forces, can assume any value between 0 and that value.

So I've decided to solve the problem below without this assumption

$\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar$

**Solution**
Here I suppose that effective wall friction coefficient varies $ \color{blue}{0}$ and $ \color{blue}{\mu_f= w}$ and effective floor friction coefficient varies between $ \color{blue}{0}$ and $ \color{blue}{\mu_f= f}$.

Thus:

**On the floor:**  $\color{blue}{F_H <= f F_V}$  but 
$\color{blue}{F_H = H}\;$ (at the figure), therefore
$\color{blue}{F_V >= (1/f)H}$

Which means that we can define $\color{blue}{q}$ so that:

$\color{blue}{F_V = (1/q) H} \quad$ where  $\color{blue}{q <= f}$

**On the wall:** $ \color{blue}{W_V <= w  W_H\quad}$ but 
$\color{blue}{W_H = H}\;$ (at the figure), therefore
$ \color{blue}{W_V <= w  H}$

Which means that we can define $\color{blue}{r}$ so that:

$\color{blue}{W_V = r H} \quad$ where  $\color{blue}{r <= w}$

**Calculation**
So we have $\color{blue}{F_V = (1/q) H} \quad$ where  $\color{blue}{q <= f}\quad$ and $\quad\color{blue}{W_V = r  H}$

From `(1)` at the figure: $\color{blue}{F_V \cos\, a  - 2H \sin\, a - W_V \cos\, a  = 0}$, so

$$ \color{blue}{(1/q) H \cos\, a  - 2H \sin\, a - rH \cos\, a  = 0}\\
\color{blue}{( 1/q - r) \cos\, a - 2 \sin\, a = 0}\\
\color{blue}{\tan\, a = ( [1/q - r]/2 )}\\
\color{blue}{ a = g(q,r) = {\rm atan}\,([1/q - r]/2 )}$$

Notice that the lesser $\color{blue}{q}$ or  $\color{blue}{r}$, the bigger the tangent value and, therefore, the angle.

Accordingly using the maximum friction for floor and wall, we have the minimum angle for ladder don't slip down.

So using $\color{blue}{f=0.4}\;$ and $\color{blue}{w=0.3}\;$ then $\color{blue}{a >=  g(f,w) = 47.7^{\circ}}$ is the right answer.

$\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar$

So uses then maximum friction on the wall and floor is enough to solve this kind of problem for any coefficients of friction

Comment: I'm not sure whether your answer is correct or not, but note that it's not inconsistent with the given answer:  both you and the given answer find that the minimum angle is 48°.

Comment: The minimum angle of the ladder DOES correspond to the maximum static friction force.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. The results of your calculations in parts (a) and (b) seems to be that the angle a has to be >= 48˚ and also <=51˚. Am I interpreting your answer correctly? Are you saying that the ladder won't slip if the angle a is in the interval [48˚, 51˚] but will slip if the angle is either smaller or larger than angles in this interval?

Comment: Yes, my conclusion is that, with this data, the ladder could be between 48  and 51 degrees  for don't slip

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum - I think that your result for (b) should be that a>51˚, not a<=51˚. See Michael Seifert's answer. Looking at the problem intuitively, doesn't it make sense that for the ladder to be prevented from slipping due to wall friction that the angle a should be greater than some value rather than less than some value?

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422352/static-equilibrium-ladder-against-a-wall-how-far-can-person-ascend/423230#423230

Comment: Finally, I've got the sense.  You should the problem like I do above, (there would be a small error), but the final answer is the union of solutions, but I've proved that the second part is useless because is contained in the first part.  @SamuelWeir,  yes, doesn't make sense, but I would want that the calculations prove that.

Answer (score 1):

To see that the answer given is correct, return to equation (1) in the linked image:
$$
F_V \cos a - 2 H \sin a - W_V \cos a = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \tan a = \frac{F_V - W_V}{2 H} = \frac{F_V}{2 F_H} - \frac{W_V}{2 W_H}.
$$
Note that $\tan a$ can be arbitrarily large, since the ratio $F_V/F_H$ can be arbitrarily large.  Your error in **(b)** above is to assume that $F_V/F_H$ was exactly equal to $2.5 = 1/\mu_f$;  but it can be *any* value greater than $2.5$, which means that angles greater than 51° are perfectly fine.

By looking at the possible values of $F_V/F_H$ and $W_V/W_H$, you can show that $\tan a \geq 1.1$, meaning that $a \geq 47.7^\circ$.  I'll leave it to you to fill in this gap.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've undestood your answer, I will try to make my question clearer.

Comment: Finally, I've got the sense. You should the problem like I do above, ( there  would be a small error), but the final answer should be  the union of solutions, but I've proved that the second part is useless because is contained in the first part.